# Mongodb Switching db Convention packs

Tags: .net, mongodb

We designed mongodb with account-base databases.Every account has same collections but holding their data seperate databases in mongodb.
But I got memory leak in .net core application.I'm registering convention pack everytime I switched the db.I believe it caused problem.But if I'dont register ı got error.

```
protected virtual void SefDefaultConventions()
        {
            var pack = new ConventionPack();
            pack.Add(new LowerCaseElementNameConvention());
            pack.Add(new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true));
            pack.Add(new StringIdStoredAsObjectIdConvention());
            ConventionRegistry.Register("Default Conventions", pack, t => true);
        }
```

I'm using mongoDb.Driver 2.11.4 .net 6

Thanks

Comment: `memory leak` what does it mean?